# How to substitute xml tags and value in java program with regular expression

Tags: java, xml, regex

i've to load an XML in a java Program

```
<BidirectionalLink>
      <bidirKey>12</bidirKey>
      <upStreamLink>
        <uniLinkKey>1</uniLinkKey>
        <maxBandwidth>0</maxBandwidth>
        <maxReservableBandwidth>0</maxReservableBandwidth>
        <unreservedBandwidth/>
        <maxLspBandwidth/>
        <teMetric>0</teMetric>
        <igpMetric>0</igpMetric>
        <adminGroups>0</adminGroups>
        <ageing>0.0</ageing>
        <bolOverheadLoss>0.0</bolOverheadLoss>
        <patchLoss>0.0</patchLoss>
        <minNumberChannel>0</minNumberChannel>
        <maxNumberChannel>0</maxNumberChannel>
        <linkComponentList>
          <LinkComponent>
            <linkComponentKey>1</linkComponentKey>
            <wdmSpanList>
              <WdmSpan>
                <spanKey>1</spanKey>
                <lenght>0.0</lenght>
                <spanLoss>0.0</spanLoss>
```

and i want to substitute all the value of the tags like BidirKey, uniLinkKey, linkComponentKey, spanKey (that finish with "Key" ) with 0. so, like that

```
<BidirectionalLink>
      <bidirKey>0</bidirKey>
      <upStreamLink>
        <uniLinkKey>0</uniLinkKey>
        <maxBandwidth>0</maxBandwidth>
        <maxReservableBandwidth>0</maxReservableBandwidth>
        <unreservedBandwidth/>
        <maxLspBandwidth/>
        <teMetric>0</teMetric>
        <igpMetric>0</igpMetric>
        <adminGroups>0</adminGroups>
        <ageing>0.0</ageing>
        <bolOverheadLoss>0.0</bolOverheadLoss>
        <patchLoss>0.0</patchLoss>
        <minNumberChannel>0</minNumberChannel>
        <maxNumberChannel>0</maxNumberChannel>
        <linkComponentList>
          <LinkComponent>
            <linkComponentKey>0</linkComponentKey>
            <wdmSpanList>
              <WdmSpan>
                <spanKey>0</spanKey>
                <lenght>0.0</lenght>
                <spanLoss>0.0</spanLoss>
```

how can i do that i java? is there any "regular expression? i don't know them and i don't know how use them in java program.

I've tried this, but doesn't work. at the end, temp.xml contains the same key value.

```
public void allKeyToZero(String filePath){
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filePath);
            // loop all choosen tags
            List<String> tagsToBeModified = new ArrayList<String>();
            tagsToBeModified.add("Key1");
            tagsToBeModified.add("Key2");
            tagsToBeModified.add("Key3");
            tagsToBeModified.add("Key4");
            tagsToBeModified.add("Key5");
            for (String tagName : tagsToBeModified){
                if (doc.getElementsByTagName(tagName)!=null && doc.getElementsByTagName(tagName).item(0)!=null )
                    doc.getElementsByTagName(tagName).item(0).setTextContent("0");
            }

            // write the content into xml file
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("./temp.xml"));
            transformer.transform(source, result);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
            tfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException sae) {
            sae.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to avoid regex in this case and use the standard DOM XML Parser, so you can have more procise control over what do you actually modify. Here a working sample:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ModifyXMLFile {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        try {
            String filepath = "sample.xml";
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);
            // loop all choosen tags
            List<String> tagsToBeModified = new ArrayList<String>();
            tagsToBeModified.add("bidirKey");
            tagsToBeModified.add("uniLinkKey");
            tagsToBeModified.add("linkComponentKey");
            tagsToBeModified.add("spanKey");
            for (String tagName : tagsToBeModified)
                doc.getElementsByTagName(tagName).item(0).setTextContent("0");
            // write the content into xml file
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
            transformer.transform(source, result);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
            tfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException sae) {
            sae.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If you really need to set to zero all the tag with name = *key, you can easily modify the example to populate the *tagsToBeModified* list looping through all nodes with *doc.getChildNodes()*.

For more information about XML in Java, check this http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials

Comment: It' doesn't work, at the end, all the key have the same value.

Comment: That works fine for me. Maybe you have some problem writing back the doc to the file? Try to delete temp.xml from the current folder. Obviously, your example does not actually work because you use tagsToBeModified.add("Key1"); tagsToBeModified.add("Key2"); etc and those tag names (Key1,Key2,etc) do not exists, so no modifications will be done. And maybe this is explain why you inserted those "null" checks.